# compute difference of number in file using perldo

Tags: perl, vim

I have a file with two numbers

```
4     4
4      4
9         8
7     7
```

Each line may have a different number of spaces.
What I would like to do is use `perldo` to compute the difference of the two numbers:

I am trying right now

```
:perldo @a=split(/ +/, $_); $_ =  $a[0] - $a[1]
```

I think this should work but the file is not changed at all.

How can I do this using perldo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know much about perl, however this works here:

```
:perldo @a=split(/ +/, $_); $_ =  $a[0] - $a[1]; print $_
```

since you were editing the file in vim, you could consider to do it in vim way:

```
:%s/\v(\d+)\s*(\d+)/\=submatch(2)-submatch(1)
```

Comment: Instead of `print $_` at the end just return `1`. A *true* value is all that's missing: `:perldo @a=split(/ +/, $_); $_ =  $a[0] - $a[1]; 1`.

Comment: This would be my 1st line of perl code. but good to know it is same concept with awk.

Answer (score 5):

For substitution to be successful, perldo line must return `true`: if `false` is returned (or other "falsish" value e.g. 0), the change is discarded.

That's why your code doesn't change the lines correctly when the two numbers in the line are the same: the result of subtraction is 0, hence the result is discarded. This, however, works

```
:perldo @a=split(/ +/, $_); $_ = $a[0] - $a[1]; 1
```

I'd write it someway differently

```
:perldo s/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/$1-$2/e
```

but that might be a matter of style.

Answer (score 3):

Obligatory awk solution

```
:%!awk '{print $1-$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Shell one-liner:

```
perl -ne 'if ( /(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)/ ) { print $1 - $3,":$1-$3\n";}' afile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of perldo, but Perl itself seems to be as easy, or easier:

```
perl -lane 'print $F[0]-$F[1]' file.txt > output.txt
```

Or you can use the in-place edit

```
perl -i -lane 'print $F[0]-$F[1]' file.txt
```

With backup:

```
perl -i.bak -lane 'print $F[0]-$F[1]' file.txt
```

The `-a` switch is autosplit on whitespace, the `-n` switch handles input (file/stdin), `-l` handles line endings.

Comment: Looking it up, it seems to be a feature of Vim.